# Elastic Search is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

When I am giving request to Elastic search my post and put is not working

**My request**

```
POST bird/admin/1
{
    "id":"1",
    "ity":"BSP"
}
```

It should give success

But, getting **error**

```
{
   "error": "Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8] is not supported",
   "status": 406
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use application/json content type.

If you are using curl, add -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

https://www.elastic.co/blog/strict-content-type-checking-for-elasticsearch-rest-requests